# Pass all the values selected from CheckBox List Tile to next screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, checkboxlist

Basically, what I'm trying to do in my app is to have a CheckBox List Tile and the selected list tiles pass through a button to next screen in a new list just for confirmation of what the user has selected and then send the data to backend.
But don't know how to pass all the values that I display in a ListTile such as the first name, last name, id etc., I can pass only one of them.

Can somebody help me with this?

Code below for reference

```
 class AthleteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AthleteScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AthleteScreen> createState() => _AthleteScreenState();
}

class _AthleteScreenState extends State<AthleteScreen> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  Future<List<Athlete>>? futureAthletebyTeamKey;
  final List<Athlete> _athlete = [];
  var selectedAthlete = [];
  int numberOfChecks = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAthletebyTeamKey = getAthletesByTeamKey();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0Xfff7f7f5),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
                future: futureAthletebyTeamKey,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<Athlete> _athlete = snapshot.data;
    ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    cacheExtent: 34,
                                    primary: true,
                                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemCount: _athlete.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return CheckboxListTile(
                                          title:Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    'ID: ${_athlete[index].id}',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                                        fontSize: 14),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Flexible(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      '${_athlete[index].lastName} ${_athlete[index].firstName}',
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Flexible(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      '(${_athlete[index].fatherName})',
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Π: ${_athlete[index].currentMonthPresences}',
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          dense: true,
                                      value: selectedAthlete
                                           .contains(_athlete[index].id),
                                      onChanged: (val) {
                                         setState(() {
                                           if (selectedAthlete
                                               .contains(_athlete[index].id)) {
                                             selectedAthlete
                                                 .remove(_athlete[index].id);
                                            numberOfChecks--;
                                       } else {
                                       selectedAthlete.add(_athlete[index].id);
                                         numberOfChecks++;
                                       }
                                      }
                                      );
                                      print(selectedAthlete);
                                     });
                                    });
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
                          }
                          return const Center(
                            heightFactor: 20,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 60,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.grey),
                        onPressed: numberOfChecks == 0
                            ? null
                            : (() async {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                            SelectedAthletes.routeName,
                            arguments: selectedAthlete);
                              }),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const Text(
                              'NEXT',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '($numberOfChecks selected athletes)',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 14),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

and the next screen where I want to display selected List Tiles

```
class SelectedAthletes extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectedAthletes({
    Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = '/selectedAthletes';

  @override
  State<SelectedAthletes> createState() => _SelectedAthletesState();
}

class _SelectedAthletesState extends State<SelectedAthletes> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as List<Athlete>;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0Xfff7f7f5),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child:
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  cacheExtent: 34,
                  primary: true,
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: args!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'ID: ${args[index].id}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14),
                                ),
                               ],
                            ),
                           ],
                        ));
                       },
                      )
                     ],
                    ),
                  ));
                 }
```

Here I can display only the id but I want to display and the rest values in ListTile

**SOLVED**

and also I don't know what type goes after as in line

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ??? ;
```

I put as Athlete that I have on first screen but throws errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cast like this:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as List<Athlete>;
```

also you are using your args wrong, please change this line too :

```
Text(
   ID: '${args[index].id}',        // change this line
   style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14),
)
```

Comment: yes I tried it but then it throws error in  'ID: ${args.id}', that id is not a type of List<Athlete>. Thanks anyway!

Comment: what is id of args ?. I though your requirement is pass List<Athlete> to next screen ?

Comment: @kate_3dev Aw I understand, plase check my edited answer

Comment: I need to pass the selected ListTile from the previous screen that has values such as id